# Are there any Backbone.Marionette plugins for drag/drop reordering of a collection

Tags: drag-and-drop, marionette

I'm using Backbone.Marionette to render a collection and would like to be able to drag/drop to reorder the items in the list.

I found this Backbone plugin:
http://rotundasoftware.github.io/backbone.collectionView/ but would prefer not to rely on jQueryUI if possible. Also it doesn't seem as though this plugin would play nicely with a Marionette CollectionView.

Are there other plugins for this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I'm starting down the same path.

Comment: I just ended up going with [jQuery Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/). It gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that the majority of such plugins just a wrap over Jquery or other DOM library, or just plain JS code for DOM manipulation.

Anyway, Marionette View its abstraction built to separate presentation application logic. It cares for rendering data and keep view actual according model status, D&D its responsibility of DOM library.

So the way to bundle all this staff together is following:

1) You model have some default data
2) Marionette.CollectionView in charge of rendering and watching for model change to refresh itself.
3) JQ UI or other build d&d and update model on drag or other callback.

for eg:

i have view method:

`onSliderChange: function(e, obj) {
        this.model.set({ ---- });
    }`

and call it on D&D widget :

`this.$el.DD({
        drag : $.proxy(this.onSliderChange,this)
    });`